# Track alert window on Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, tracking

How can I track floating view on android using `Google Analytics`. I am talking about view adds to window using `WindowManager`
and Needed `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission.

`Activity` can tracked by `EasyTracker` using `activityStart` and `activityStop`
these methods takes `Activity` as a parameter
these methods are not exist in `View`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file under res/values/ called `analytics.xml`

And organize this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<resources>

<!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxxxxx-x</string>

<!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

<string name="com.example.project.Class">Main Activity</string>
<string name="com.example.project.Class2">Activity 2</string>

</resources>
```

And in each Class/Activity, place this before you close last bracket:

```
//Tracker method starts..

@Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // The rest of your onStart() code.


    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // The rest of your onStop() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
  }

  //Tracker method ends..
```

**Note:** Imports for tacking will be automatically added. But make sure you have already settled with Google Service and libraries into your project before doing this.

Comment: I do not have activity at all

Comment: can you have an app without Activity?

Comment: I have another Activities but I have also floating view
and BTW yes you can